# A word or phrase for this kind of metallic colouring?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is a word or phrase for the kind of metallic colouring shown in the photo, which shows a sculpture in Hong Kong? This colouring is not uniform. It has a sort of dark gold base and in places, where you might imagine it has been rubbed or stressed, it has shiny blue and purple.

I believe the site rules require me to post an example sentence. Here is one:

"Have you seen the sculpture by the harbour, the one that is ***?"

[image]

Comment: Does the color change depending on the angle you look at it (like a film of oil on water), or is it just painted/dyed with different colors in different parts?

Comment: It changes a little. There could well be the same kind of physical thing going on as with a film of oil on water.

Comment: the discoloring is  most likely not from "rubbing or stressing" but heat-based instead (or based on electroplating-times)

Comment: I agree that iridescent/anodized is correct. I also use "thin-film effect" as a way to describe these in a very general way.

Comment: I don't know what other "community members" think but straightforward "I forgot this word" or "which word in the dictionary means" questions, let's say, "Questions where the entire answer is typing a single word, such as 'Iridescence'" - should be on the learning site?

Comment: @Fattie ELL is intended for people who are learning or teaching English _as a foreign language_. There's no evidence that that is true here. So, no, it shouldn't be on ELL simply because it's too easy for ELU.

Comment: @KillingTime - yes, but anyone who doesn't use a commonplace word would not be a native English speaker, so that's the case here.  "I forgot the word for immortal" questions are surely for ELL ????

Comment: @Fattie I can't claim any scientific measurement but I suspect a fair proportion of SWRs are native speakers looking for _le mot juste_ for a given circumstance. They wouldn't consider themselves language learners simply because they don't know a particular word or phrase.

Comment: @KillingTime - fair enough. I guess, i think in this case OP is a E.L.L. so ... and it's such a basic word ... I suppose "in this case" my feeling is move it.  I guess I was wrong to see it as a general issue.

Comment: I know it's not from rubbing or stressing. Now I come to think of it, I'm not sure the colour on this sculpture does change much, or at all, when viewed from different angles. But the effect the designer wanted may have been to replicate colour patterns that do. _Edit_: Knowledge of the range of meanings of the word _iridescent_ doesn't seem to be widespread among native speakers. Iridescence is not necessarily to do with changes in colour when viewpoints change. _Iridiscence_ is the best word in answer to the question, though. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

These colours have to do with *[iridescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iridescence)*;

> (Wikipedia) **Iridescence** (also known as **goniochromism**) is the phenomenon of certain surfaces that appear gradually to change colour as the angle of view or the angle of illumination changes. Iridescence is caused by wave interference of light in microstructures or thin films. Examples of iridescence include soap bubbles, feathers, butterfly wings and seashell nacre, and minerals such as opal.

[image]

The colours characterized by this phenomenon can be called *[iridescent colours](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Iridescent+colours&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)*.

[Animal Biochromes and Structural Colours: Physical, ... - Denis Llewellyn Fox · 1976](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Animal_Biochromes_and_Structural_Colours/tti9WX3lL70C?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22iridescent+colours%22&pg=PA41&printsec=frontcover)  IRIDESCENT COLOURS The finely colour'd Feathers of some Birds , and particularly those of Peacocks Tails , do , in the very same part of the Feather , appear of several Colours in several Positions of the Eye , after the same manner ...

Comment: It reminds me of the iridescence you get on [bismuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bismuth) crystals https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1f/Wismut_Kristall_und_1cm3_Wuerfel.jpg/1024px-Wismut_Kristall_und_1cm3_Wuerfel.jpg

Comment: @PM2Ring The variety and vividness of the colours on bismuth crystals are startling.

Comment: Yes, _iridescent_ or _prismatic_.

Comment: @MetaEd I think there is no change in the colours  of the spectrum as the angle of vision changes, and so the two terms are probably not synonymous.  Where do you get this equivalence?

Comment: Agreed, the picture shows iridescence. Just want to throw out the related "opalescent" and "pearlescent" in case it helps anyone in the future.

Comment: @LPH changing as angle changes is not a necessary part of what iridescent means. I know search results from some online abridged dictionaries can give that impression. But the primary sense is "displaying colours like those of the rainbow, or those reflected from soap-bubbles and the like". A secondary sense is "glittering or flashing with colours which change according to the position from which they are viewed". This was a natural development from the fact that the colors of some iridescent objects (sense 1) do change according to angle (sense 2).

Comment: @MetaEd I wasn't aware of that polysemic property of the form "iridescence", and in fact your description corresponds precisely to the definition in the SOED. As  "prismatic" can mean "Of varied colours, brightly coloured, brillant" (SOED), I suppose there is some incentive to use it, yet it seems excessively lacking in specificity, misleading even: who thinks decomposition of light thinks first in terms of a particular array of colours, always the same, "changing", of course, but nevertheless only in a particular order of spatial occurrence  (1/3)

Comment: @MetaEd (rainbow, decomposition through a prism, the spectrum, … ). Using such a term would license the use of the term "kaleidoscopic", which also implies the show of a great variety of colours, and "change" again, but which implies also the idea of regular geometric shapes in most realizations (https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&sca_esv=82cfab1f5a57e002&q=kaleidoscopic+pictures&tbm=isch&source=lnms&prmd=ivnbz&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiapuqCupWFAxVqUaQEHSgnD-AQ0pQJegQIERAB&biw=1920&bih=993&dpr=1). (2/3)

Comment: @MetaEd  I don't think these terms should be used synonymously, I believe that they become misnomers in such a case, the more so as they refer to  totally different underlying physical phenomena (decomposition of light, reflection in mirrors). (3/3)

Answer (score 13):

If I were attempting to create such a piece, I would describe the process of coloring it as *[anodizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anodizing)*, or the end product as *anodized metal*.

While most anodizing is done only for the protection it offers and doesn't create colors, the use of coloration with it is common.

Although dyes can be uses with anodization, this particular piece looks to me like it is mostly likely not dyed, but using interference coloring.

> (Wikipedia) Interference-colored anodized aluminum parts exhibit a distinctive quality: their color varies when viewed from different angles.

Youtube video of a more technical description for coloring by anodizing:
[Anodizing (Or the beauty of corrosion)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ZhVOy-ytJY).

Comment: You might want to add the closely matching picture from this [Titanium Finishing Company](https://www.titaniumfinishing.com/capabilities/titanium-anodize-colors/) advert. Of course, many colours are possible.

Answer (score 3):

The colours are likely created by heat treating or anodizing, depending on the metal.  That refers to the process, however, not the colour itself.  I would use iridescense myself, but I've also heard the term "Oilslick"

Comment: +1. I would use “iridescent”/“iridescence” for describing the visual effect, and “oilslick” for specifying the finish: “Items with an oilslick anodization are iridescent.”

Answer (score 2):

[Pearlescent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pearlescent) and [nacreous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nacreous) are two more synonyms of *iridescent* that could be used to describe such an effect.

Answer (score 1):

Opalesque, having the same irridesent quality of a opal

Comment: You should include a source (e.g. dictionary) definition or other citation/evidence that demonstrates to the OP the use of the word and that it is applicable.

Comment: What a great answer from a new contributor.  the only thing of value on the page as an alternate to iridescence.

Comment: *Opalescent* is far more common than *opalesque* and would be a better choice.